# Positioning a div underneath a table whose height can vary

Tags: html, css

I would like to know how to position a div underneath a table whose height can vary.

This is for a shopping cart backend page: I have a table with the shopping cart items which can be a list of anything between 1 and 15 items, and can therefore have 1 through 15 rows. About 100px underneath this I would like to have a div containing input fields to collect the billing and shipping address. I don't want to have to set the height of the table to anything specific, just the height of the number of rows it requires, with the address div right below it.

I've looked into and experimented with all of the CSS positioning possibilities but found nothing helpful. Please help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just put the div right after the table, and give it a css style that includes `margin-top:100px;`

Comment: Or put `margin-bottom` on the `table`. Whatever makes more sense.

Comment: Perfect! This works excellently, thank you for answering my question so quickly :-)